# How to trace running instructions/taken branches on physical Android smartphone?

Tags: android, debugging, code-coverage, trace, test-coverage

This is the situation: I have my own smartphone and I want to trace every time I make a service call with

```
adb shell service call ...
```

which instructions are covered or which branches are taken in the service code (both java and c).

I tried to give a look to hardware solutions, but it read that vendors usually disable this debugging option.

Any ideas or useful tool for me?

Comment: working with frida, I'll be back soon with an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/) is able to do that now. .